# Proving that there is an exact sequence

Tags: homological-algebra

[image]

This is what I got so far before getting stuck

Proof: Show that $im \iota \subseteq ker f$. Let $g \in im \ \iota$. Then there is some $n \in ker\  f$ such that $g = \iota(n)$. If $f: M \rightarrow N$ is surjective, then $im \ \iota = M$. Since $g \in im \ \iota$, then $f(g) = f(\iota(n)) = 0$ implies $g \in ker f$. So $im \ \iota \subseteq ker f$. Next we show that $ker f \subseteq im \ \iota$. Let $h \in ker f$, then the definition of $ker f$ means that $h \in im \ \iota$ if $f$ is surjective.

In the problem I used $\iota $ as the map from $0 \rightarrow ker f$. I also used the definitions of both the $im \iota$ and $ker f$. My question is whether if this outline makes any sense or if there's an appropriate way to approach the problem. I'm not sure if I should approach the relations $imf = ker \iota'$, where $\iota': N \rightarrow co ker f$. Similarly but using $co ker f$ instead of $ker f$. Confusion arises when I use the definition of exactness, i.e. $im \ \iota = ker \ f$ and then there's the $ker \ f $ in the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow ker f \rightarrow M \rightarrow N$. Are these two $ker f$ the same? Sorry this feels like a dumb question.

Comment: Voted up as there is part of the proof.

Comment: Suggestion: put a little more effort in, like using LaTeX rather than asking us to read your messy writing, photographed from something with ugly reflections obscuring stuff. Doing so will make our lives easier (and we're the ones doing the favor, right?) AND will make your question more searchable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that a sequence is exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786534/showing-that-a-sequence-is-exact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion map $\iota:\ker(f)\rightarrow M$ and the quotient map $\mathcal{Q}:N\rightarrow \text{coker}(f)$ should do the trick.

First look at $0\rightarrow\ker(f)\overset{\iota}{\rightarrow} M$. The first arrow is the zero map, whose image is $\{0\}$ and this is the same as the kernel of the inclusion map $\iota$.

Now look at $\ker(f)\overset{\iota}{\rightarrow}M\overset{f}{\rightarrow}N$. The image of $\iota$ is precisely $\ker(f)$, so there is nothing to check here. (To answer your question, the $\ker(f)$ in the exact sequence is the kernel of the given map $f:M\rightarrow N$).

Have a go at the last part, just by computing the image and kernel of the relevant maps.